# Javascript MVC ASP.NET simple if condition not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I've a following asp.net mvc razor view code which doesn't seem to be working:

```
@{ 
  bool Condition1=Model.SomeObject.Condition1;
  bool Condition2 = Model.SomeObject.Condition2;
}

if('@Condition1') {
    alert('hi condition1');
} else if ('@Condition2') {
    alert('hi condition2');
} else { 
    alert('hi condition3'); 
}
```

Here is what not working:

1. when Condition2 is True the javascript  'hi condition2' never get hit.

I also tried with this below and still not working.

> else if ('@Condition2' ==true){

Am I missing any casting here, please?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it isnt hitting the first branch? Maybe conditions 1 and 2 arent mutually exclusive?

Comment: @flybyte: There is a typing mistake as first alert didn't have close quote. Is this correct in your code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to your code `alert('hi condition2')` should work only when Condition1 == false and Condition2 == true.
In addition, you shouldn't wrap `@Condition1` and `@Condition2` in quotes `'`. It is bool, not a string.
The matter is in JavaScript any condition with not empty string equals to true.
One more thing: **.NET** bool converts to string as `True` or `False` (in upper case). In other side, **JS** bool values are `true` and `false`.
So try:

```
if (@(Condition.ToString().ToLower())) { ... }
```

Comment: if i remove quotes, it complains conditional compiliation not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(@(Condition1.ToString().ToLower())) {}
```

C# boolean is True and js's is true.

What you have won't work as the text 'false' in js counts as a "truthy" value (empty string is falsey).

Comment: THanks @Steve your solution works as well. I accepted DotNEt ninja solution as as per answer date. THanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(@Condition1) {
    alert('hi condition1');
} else if (@Condition2) {
    alert('hi condition2');
} else { 
    alert('hi condition3'); 
}
```